# TableviewController delegate not returning value

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitableview

I have a tableview controller that is a static table used for request data. When someone selects a row, it displays a new tableview controller with options using a modal segue, the user selects a option and then presses the 'hecho' (done) button and the value should be returned to the first table view controller, but it just not happening. If I inspect the delegate it just says null. What could I be doing wrong?
**The story board**
[image]

**First table**

**AgregarCitaTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController.h"

@interface AgregarCitaTableViewController : UITableViewController <SeleccionarPacienteTableViewControllerDelegate>


@end
```

**AgregarCitaTableViewController.m**

```
#import "AgregarCitaTableViewController.h"
#import "SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController.h"

@interface AgregarCitaTableViewController ()
{
    NSDictionary *datosPaciente;
}

@end

@implementation AgregarCitaTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)paciente:(NSDictionary *)paciente
{
    datosPaciente = paciente;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [datosPaciente objectForKey:@"nombre"];

}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"listaPacientes"] )
    {
        SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

**Second Table**

**SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController.h**

```
@protocol SeleccionarPacienteTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)paciente:(NSDictionary *)paciente;

@end

@interface SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    id delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic,assign)id<SeleccionarPacienteTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController.m**

```
#import "SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController.h"

@interface SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *todosPacientes;
    NSDictionary *paciente;
    NSInteger checkmarkedRow;
}

@end

@implementation SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *hecho = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(hecho)];
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:hecho];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelar)];
    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:cancelar];
    //Llamada asincrona, cargar las citas
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(cargarDatos) withObject:nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return todosPacientes.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSDictionary *object;
    object = todosPacientes[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"nombre"];
    if(checkmarkedRow == indexPath.row){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Guardar nombre del paciente selccionado
    paciente = todosPacientes[indexPath.row];

    // In cellForRow... we check this variable to decide where we put the checkmark
    checkmarkedRow = indexPath.row;

    // We reload the table view and the selected row will be checkmarked
    [tableView reloadData];

    // We select the row without animation to simulate that nothing happened here :)
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

    // We deselect the row with animation
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void) cargarDatos
{
    //Path donde se encuentra el plist con los datos
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"pacientes" ofType:@"plist"];

    //Guardamos las citas en un NSMutableArray
    todosPacientes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}

- (void) hecho
{
    /*Is anyone listening
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(paciente:)])
    {
        //send the delegate function with the amount entered by the user
        [delegate paciente:paciente];
    }*/
    [self.delegate paciente:paciente];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) cancelar
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


@end
```

**Solution:**
Im not really sure how it worked or even if this is the real solution. I used the anwer of Hani Ibrahim and it didn't work but what he said was right. Then i just changed [delegate paciente:paciente] in the hecho method for [self.delegate paciente:paciente] and it worked.
I hope this can help someone.

Comment: This might not be the issue, but you instance variable in `SeleccionarPacienteTableViewControllerDelegate` is not needed, especially if you are doing `@synthesize delegate = _delegate`. The naming could potentially obscure whether you are accessing the ivar or the property.

Comment: did you check the value of paciente inside hecho that it is not nil ?

Comment: yes , i already checked and paciente is not null inside of hecho. Also thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your seque display UINavigationController and not SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController

**Change this method**

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"listaPacientes"] )
    {
        SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

**to be**

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"listaPacientes"] )
    {
        UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;
        SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController *viewController = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        viewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

You have another problem

When doing this

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)id<SeleccionarPacienteTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

and this

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

Then Your property will work with an instance variable called '_delegate' as you are saying `@synthesize delegate = _delegate;`

However this code

```
@interface SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    id delegate;
}
```

defines a new instance variable called `delegate` which is completely different than your property

So to access your property you can use `self.delegate` or `_delegate` and **NOT** `delegate` as it is another instance variable !

Comment: I just tried this, but it didn't work , i have been trying to use the debugger to find an answer, so far y can see that delegate is nil, but _delegate is not, and at the end the method paciente inside of AgregarCitaTableViewController its not begin called. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure of the segue identifier ... please make sure that he enters the if condition?

Comment: Thanks for the help, i just made it work, im not really sure how, but i know that i was missing your answer also. The only difference was that instead of [delegate paciente:paciente] i changed it to [self.delegate paciente:paciente] and now it work, thanks a lot

Comment: I have found another problem with your code and updated my another ... please check it

Comment: Thanks! now i know this was the other problem and why.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in prepareForSegue. The destinationViewController is a UINavigationController and not a SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController.

You have to access the first child of the destinationViewController to get your SeleccionarPacienteTableViewController.

Replacing `segue.destinationViewController` with `[segue.destinationViewController topViewController]` will probably solve your problem.